# TypeScript with empty function as parameter?

Tags: typescript

I have a piece of code that I am having a hard time to understand. I'm new to TypeScript.

```
registerCommands(registry: CommandRegistry): void {
    registry.registerCommand(FensterCommands.HELLOWORLD);
    registry.registerHandler(FensterCommands.HELLOWORLD.id, {
        isEnabled: () => true,
        execute: () => this.messageService.info('Hello World!')
    });
}
```

Could someone help me understand the above code? The thing I don't understand is the second JSON-like parameter within `registry.registerHandler(...)`. What type does this parameter value have, that is located within curly brackets `{...}`? The first parameter has the name `isEnabled`, right? And its value is what? Is it `()` or `true`? What does the empty function `()` mean? Does the entire line `() => true` end in being a comparison that ends in `true/false`?

Is that more or less correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What type the second paramter of **registry.registerHandler** is, depends on the definition of the function, it is an object but
the informations you provided are not clear enough - it could be an interface or even any...

Despite this:

```
   isEnabled: () => true,
```

likely sets **isEnabled** to a function without parameter which returns a boolean value

```
  execute: () => this.messageService.info('Hello World!')
```

likely sets **execute** to a function without parameter which will return the type of **this.messageService.info('Hello World!')** returns.

Both functions are declared with [ES6 Arrow functions](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html)

It could be also written as:

(Assuming **this.messageService.info('Hello World!')** will return nothing/void)

```
{
       isEnabled: function() { return true; },
       execute: function() { return this.messageService.info('Hello World!'); }
}
```

Comment: ```likely sets execute to a void function```. Wrong! Since there are no curly brackets, the line ```this.serviceMessage.info("Hello World!")``` is not the body, but the return value. It depends on what does ```info``` return to tell the return type of that arrow function

Comment: @codeteq Following your example how it also could have been written, am I right to understand that within that you declare two functions, one `isEnabled()` and the other `execute()`? So what sense does it make to put both within curly brackets? Is that like a namespace? Or a class with two methods?

Comment: @Socrates, it's an object. It's like an associative array in php or a hastable in other languages. It's properties can be accessed through dot notation. You should have learned about objects before learning about classes, cause class intances are objects.

Comment: @StefanOctavian Ok, so it's basically an object that will be parsed to the type wanted by the method `registerHandler(..., ...)` right? I'm firm in Java, but TypeScript has some strange way to write things. I guess that's normal when learning a new syntax. ;)

Comment: @codeteq Why could I not just write `isEnabled: true`? Why must I do the extra step of adding the round brackets `isEnabled: () => true`?

Comment: @Socrates, Approximatively. The object won't get parsed to the parameter type, but it needs to match it. It would have been great if you had learned javascript, before learning typescript. That way, you could have understood where does all this syntax come from (since typescript is just a static superset of javascript, after all)

Comment: @Socrates, you have to add the parantheses to make it a function returning true, not the value true. This way, the object will match the function signature.

Comment: @StefanOctavian Ok, kind of a random question, but would you have any suggestion for a book on JavaScript for an experienced Java/C#/VB programmer? Better get Springer or O'Reilly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168933/discussion-between-stefan-octavian-and-socrates).

Comment: @StefanOctavian thank you for the hint!
I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The second parameter is an object literal with the fields `isEnabled` and `execute`. You might be able to pass an object literal with more fields, without the definition of `registerHandler` it's impossible to tell.

As for the `() => true` that is an arrow function, a function with no parameters `()` that returns `true`. So the type of `isEnabled` is a function that returns a boolean and takes no parameters.

The `execute` field is similar, it is a function with no parameters and the body `this.messageService.info('Hello World!')`